# How can I save files provided as byte[] in angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, filesaver.js

I request from my Spring Boot Rest Api a file and I receive it as a byte array. I want to save it using my Angular client.

Download method:

```
download(dataSet: DataSet) {
    this.dataSetService.download(dataSet.publicId).subscribe(
      data => saveAs(new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}), dataSet.name)
    )
  }
```

Service download method:

```
  download(publicId: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get("/data-set/download" + publicId, {
      responseType: "arraybuffer"
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the saved files does not contain the **proper content**. It contains a random html. I have tested the `/data-set/download/publicId` in **postman** and it works. I receive proper content.

I have tried different methods like: [how to save byte array as zip in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723781/how-to-save-byte-array-as-zip-in-angular) but with no results.

Received html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Loan</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.c511231257e04e99d54a.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.3e8196928d184a6e5319.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.32326ea772b6ff50cfae.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.32326ea772b6ff50cfae.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using the wrong url, what you are receiving is the html for index.html

Comment: did you missed trailing slash in `"/data-set/download"`?

Comment: Wow...thanks for the comments. It works just fine now.